# Why aren't my social meta tags for Facebook working?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api

There's a site I'm working on and it features a jQuery UI popup with an image and a Facebook share button. The sharing mechanism already works and I just need to upgrade it with open graph meta tags. The content part of the popup is an IFrame and here's what's in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The title" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="sport" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?=$fbshareurl?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?=$fbshareurl?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is the description." />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <img src="<?=$fbshareurl?>" width="200"  align="left" /> &nbsp;
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?=$fbshareurl?>" data-layout="button" ></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=502529176549532&version=v2.0";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I've never done something like this before and I didn't write the sharing mechanism so I'm not sure how the function in the script tag works but it only shares my image and it doesn't take into account my meta tags. Any ideas as to what the problem may be?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem and it's so silly that no reader would ever benefit from finding this question.

Comment: you can delete your own question in that case.

Comment: @Maerlyn It doesn't allow me to delete it because it contains answers so I had to flag it :/

Answer (score 0):

Try add:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

to your `<html>` tag.

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using facebook object debugger.

Below is the URL

[facebook object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

Check if your meta tags are scrapped by Facebook.

Comment: Problem with that is, I'm currently not working on a live/online site. I'm working locally.

Comment: Locally it wont work because facebook wont be able to scrap your URL since it is local.